# Firebase Android - Database Trigger

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I try following number 10 from [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/?utm_campaign=featureoverview_education_functions_en_04-18-17&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=yt-desc#9), but I got a Billing Account not configure, why is that?

The function that I was going for here was when an Admin post a new content, all users will receive a push notification saying that there's a new content.

```
// Points to my News ID, new contents posted here will send push notifications to all the users via device token
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/Newsv2/{newsID}').onWrite(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    // Only send a notification when a new message has been created.
    if (snapshot.previous.val()) {
        return;
    }
    // Notification details, I modified it for test use first.
    const text = snapshot.val().text;
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Test Notification",
            body: "",
            icon: "",
            click_action: ""
        }
    };
    // Get the list of device tokens.
    //root/
    //   Usersv2/
    //         userID/
    //             -name
    //             -age
    //             -device_token
    //The above how it'll looks like in the Database
    return admin.database().ref('/Usersv2/{userID}/{device_token}').once('value').then(allTokens => {
        if (allTokens.val()) {
            // Listing all tokens.
            const tokens = Object.keys(allTokens.val());
            // Send notifications to all tokens.
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
                // For each message check if there was an error.
                const tokensToRemove = [];
                response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
                    const error = result.error;
                    if (error) {
                        console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
                        // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
                        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                            tokensToRemove.push(allTokens.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
                        }
                    }
                });
                return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out what you are trying to ask from your question.

Comment: Free accounts have few limitations, May be the operation you are trying to do have some restriction, see the limitation of Firebase account once before you try. all the best.

Comment: For example: I have an Account which can create new posts. What I wanted to ask was, whenever this account made a post. A notification will be sent to all Users who registered through the app saying that there is a new content.